# Is the union a basis of that extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, transcendence-theory

Suppose that $H$ is a trancendental basis of the extension $A/F$ and $K$ is a trancendental basis of the extension $B/F$.

So, $H$ is the maximal among all the subsets of $A$ that are $F$-algebraic independent and $K$ is the maximal among all the subsets of $B$ that are $F$-algebraic independent.

Does it hold that $H\cup K$ is a trancendental basis of the extension $AB/F$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Consider $A=F(X^2)\subseteq B=F(X,Y),\ H=\{X^2\},\ K=\{X,Y\}$. When $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: In this case we have that $AB=F(X^3, XY)$, or not? Then a trancendental basis would we teh $\{X^3,XY\}$, right?

Comment: About $A$ and $B$ we have the following: They are extensions of the field $F$, that are contained in a bigger field.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the meaning of $AB$: if $A$ and $B$ are both subfields of a larger field $U$, $AB$ is the smallest subfield of $U$ which contains both $A$ and $B$. So, $AB=B$. However, if you have affection for seeing it as $\{\alpha\beta\in U\,:\,\alpha\in A,\ \beta\in B\}$, let me remind you that $\frac1X\in B$.

Comment: Ahh... So, if $A\subseteq B$, then $AB=B$, right?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ah ok... So, if $H$ or $K$ is the maximal among all the subsets of $AB$ that are $F$-algebraic independent, then $H$ or $K$ is a trancendental basis of the extension $AB/F$. Right? If none of them is the maximal among all the subsets of $AB$ that are $F$-algebraic independent?

Comment: Simply, union ofm algebraically independent sets over $F$ might not be algebraically independent over $F$.

Comment: Ah ok... So, we cannot find in general a trancendental basis of the extension $AB/F$ ?

Comment: We can, but not in that way.

Comment: Ahh... Could you give me a hint how we could find it?

Comment: Is a trancendental basis in that case the set $D$ with $H,K\subset D\subseteq H\cup K$ ?